# Duplicate Value insertion in Hashmap

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, hashmap

There is a Hashmap (o) which takes string as a key and Order Object as value. Order has an Arraylist of OrderLines. Here I have to add multiple orders to the map. The problem is my hashmap prints out unique first and second keys (order 1 and Order 2) but the last inserted value as value for both keys (duplicate order in all entries). Can you please help me debug the problem ?

**Main Class** :

```
    Map<String, Order> o = new HashMap<String, Order>();

    Order c = new Order();

    c.add(new OrderLine(new Item("book", (float) 12.49), 1));
    c.add(new OrderLine(new Item("music CD", (float) 14.99), 1));

    o.put("Order 1", c);

    // Reuse cart for an other order
    c.clearCart(); // this.orderLines.clear() in the order class 

    c.add(new OrderLine(new Item("imported box of chocolate", 10), 1));
    c.add(new OrderLine(new Item("imported bottle of perfume", (float)     47.50), 1));

    o.put("Order 2", c);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Order> entry : o.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("*******" + entry.getKey() + entry.getValue().get(0).getItem().getDescription() + "*******");
    }
```

**Order class** :

```
class Order {

private List<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(OrderLine o) throws Exception {
    orderLines.add(o);
}

public OrderLine get(int i) {
    return orderLines.get(i);
}

public void clearCart() {
    this.orderLines.clear();
}
}
```

**OrderLine class:**

```
private int quantity;
private Item item;

public OrderLine(Item item, int quantity) throws Exception {
    if (item == null) {
        System.err.println("ERROR - Item is NULL");
        throw new Exception("Item is NULL");
    }
    assert quantity > 0;
    this.item = item;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
}
```

**Item class:**

```
class Item {

    private String description;
    private float price;

    public Item(String description, float price) {
        super();
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    }
```

Comment: where is OrderLine class. That's how your code does. Post entire code, I'll suggest fix. Looks like c.clearCart() is not able to clear cart

Comment: Added all the code

Comment: How do you get `entry.getValue().get(0)` at the SOP in the for loop in the main class ?

Comment: See my answer. This question should not be downvoted like it is. There is more than enough code to understand the issue and the answer actually lies within Java's behind-the-scene workings. It is perfectly understandable that the OP could not find the answer as he did not know the question.

Comment: Not sure why people keep down voting posts

Comment: The order which is used as Value object in map has a get(i) method which returns the specific orderline @SurajitBiswas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Java is pass-by-value, it is perfectly valid to alter what's at the end of a reference. This is what you are doing, albeit inadvertently.

Think about what you're doing: you're adding `c` to the list, then clearing `c,` re-initializing it, and adding it again.

As you never use the `new` keyword, you're never actually allocating a new portion of memory for `c.` It is still pointing to the same `Order.` Simultaneously, you did not add a clone of `c` to the list. You added `c.`

In other words, when you call `c.clearCart(),` you're also clearing the first `Order` in list `o` as said `Order` *is* `c.`

You could either use the `new` keyword by replacing:

```
c.clearCart();
```

with

```
c = new Order();
```

Or, you could add a clone of `c` to list `o` instead of `c` itself, so that when you call `c.clearCart(),` you are not clearing the first element in list `o.` In other words, replace:

```
o.put("Order 1", c);
```

with

```
o.put("Order 1", c.clone());
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) for more information.

**EDIT:**

I forgot one part, though it may be obvious. I stated that clearing `c` will also clear the first element in list `o,` because that element *is* `c.` However, I forgot to mention that, by transition, re-initializing `c`
also means re-initializing this element simultaneously. Consequently, when you add `c` again, you have two elements initialized with the same fields.